# Godot Game audioplayer will not load when get_tree().reload_current_scene() called after audioplayer node called

Tags: game-development, godot

This is my first question ever in an online coding forum, so apologies if I am not clear. I am creating a simple platform game in Godot. It has a player, enemy, coin and a platform. When player collides with coin, score goes up and `play_coin_sfx()` is played, no problems here.

```
onready var audioPlayer : Node = get_node("/root/MainScene/Camera2D/AudioPlayer")

func collect_coin(value):
    
    score += value 
    ui.set_score_text(score)
    audioPlayer.play_coin_sfx()
```

BUT if I repeat the above code approach for playing the `play_die_sfx()` I am unable to get the audio to play.

```
onready var musicPlayer : Node = get_node("/root/MainScene/MusicPlayer")

func die ():
    musicPlayer.play_die_sfx()
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

STRANGLEY if I comment out the `get_tree().reload_current_scene()` the `musicPlayer.play_die_sfx()` does play. I tried swapping around the lines of the `func die()` but no luck. I am trying to get the `musicPlayer.play_die_sfx()` to play and then reload the scene. Help would be much appreciated and yes I have check Godot online help and stackoverflow but no luck so far. Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload the scene, the musicPlayer node is destroyed and the sound stops. You can try to wait for the sound to end by executing yield(musicPlayer, "finished") before reloading the scene.

Comment: Thanks it worked, after I looked up what yield does as I was not familiar with this . Add the code you suggestedfunc die ():
 musicPlayer.play_die_sfx()
 yield(musicPlayer,"finished")
 get_tree().reload_current_scene()